# Form isn't submitting after JSON object is null

Tags: php, jquery, forms

At the begining I return false for form submittion

```
$("#Login").submit(function () {
    return false;
});
```

And when 1 condition met

```
$.post(url,data,function(resp)
{
    $('#'+id).parent().find('.alert-danger').remove();
    if(resp === " ")
    {
        $("#Login").submit(function () {
        return true;
        });
        console.log("Dang");
    }
```

I want when object `resp` is empty to turn form submition to true and when hitting Submit Button, form should submit.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if(resp === " ")
```

To:

```
if(resp === "")
```

Comment: changed that but also form isn't submitting.

Comment: form isnt submitting because you have `$("#Login").submit(function () {
    return false;
});`

Comment: But i want to cghange this when 1 condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

Change `resp === " "` to `resp === ""`

Comment: changed that but also form isn't submitting.